# Django-models: CharField with Choices atribute

Tags: django, django-models

Why its not working ??

```
DESCSPECSOFT = (
    (u'99','-'),
    (u'Load',u'Load'),
    (u'Script',u'Script'),
    (u'Load & Script',u'Load & Script'),
    )   
descSpecSoft = models.CharField(choices=DESCSPECSOFT, default=99,blank = False,null = False)
```

Thanks

EDIT:

SOry for forms instead of models my mistake

EDIT2:
"
The choices are strings, but the default is an integer.
You didn't provide any information about what "not working" means."

Not working = in template its not requierd field

Comment: What error are you getting? Is it perhaps because you're trying to access DESCSPECSOFT before you've defined it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
_CharField = partial(models.CharField, max_length=255)

DESCSPECSOFT = model_utils.Choices(
    (u'99','-'),
    (u'load',u'Load'),
    (u'script',u'Script'),
    (u'load_script',u'Load & Script'),
)
descSpecSoft = _CharField(choices=DESCSPECSOFT, default=DESCSPECSOFT.load)
```

Note that the blank and null are removed because it is required by default

Comment: I should add that
`from functools import partial`
and something else but what ? I cant finde it at google i have error 
`name 'model_utils' is not defined`

Comment: Ok i should be `from functools import partial
from model_utils import Choices` and then `_CharField = partial(models.CharField, max_length=255)

DESCSPECSOFT = Choices( (u'99','-'), (u'load',u'Load'), (u'script',u'Script'), (u'load_script',u'Load & Script'), ) descSpecSoft = _CharField(choices=DESCSPECSOFT, default=DESCSPECSOFT.load)`

Thanks for help

Answer (score 5):

Right, let's count the issues here.

1. You've used `forms.CharField`, which doesn't exist.
2. Even if it did exist, this is a model, so you should use model fields rather than form fields.
3. You've used `DESCSPECSOFT` before defining it.
4. The choices are strings, but the default is an integer.
5. You didn't provide any information about what "not working" means.

Answer (score 1):

Try
forms.ChoiceField()
and Instead of default try initial='99'

and also form fields are required by default and they do not accept null or blank, try required=True or required=False